# Analysisng IOS using Sonar

Tags: sonarqube

I am new to IOS environment and I would like to analyze my IOS projects using sonarqube. What prerequisites and how I can analyse IOS projects. Is it same as Java projects? thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

An obvious prerequisite is an instance of SonarQube. You can install your own or use [SonarCloud](https://about.sonarcloud.io/), which is free for open source projects.

Presumably you're talking about projects written in Swift or Objective-C. Commercial analyzers exist for both languages: [SonarSwift](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/codeanalyzers/sonarswift.html), [SonarCFamily for Objective-C](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/codeanalyzers/sonarcfamilyforobjectivec.html).

If you're running your own SonarQube intance, you'll need to obtain a trial license, and then the docs ([SonarSwift](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/codeanalyzers/sonarjava.html), [SonarCFamily for Objective-C](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarCFamily+for+Objective-C)) will get you started with analysis. If you're using SonarCloud, just follow the onboarding tutorial.

Comment: Thanks G.Ann, I wonder if we can analyze Android and IOS projects rather than sonar-scanner. is sonar-scanner is prerequisite? or can we do it without it too

Comment: You need _some_ scanner installed locally. There is a [range of choices](docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN)